# Sudo will break importing my script

Tags: linux, shell, centos, sudo

I have a shell script (my.sh) which imports another file (myfile.env). The name of myfile.env is passed as an argument to my.sh. It works well as root and I want the ability to run it to be given for other users via sudo.

myfile.env

```
some shell scripts........
```

my.sh

```
ENVFILE="$1"
if [ -e $ENVFILE ] ; then
    . $ENVFILE
fi
```

I call the my.sh as

```
sudo /abc/def/my.sh myfile.sh
```

sudoers file goes as below

```
Cmnd_Alias MYSUDO = /abc/def/my.sh, /bin/bash
%mygroup ALL = MUSUDO
```

Unfortunately this results with an error in the 3rd line in the my.sh code above. It says

```
.: myfile.env: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

its funny that i get this error after a check on file exist returned true.

sudo -s and -E options didn't help (don't know whether I used them correctly)

Can someone please help me to resolve this? I am using CeNT OS 6.5

Comment: `‍‍‍ENVFILE = "$1"‍` is mistake, change it to `ENVFILE="$1"`

Comment: @Babyy Thanks but it didn't solve the issue. I'll change he qn anyway.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks Glenn, but I cant do that... i am not allowed to change the my.sh and it uses the file name (ie. $1 or "myfile.env") for some other work. If I pass the full path it breaks. Thanks for your suggestion though. Thats why I tries -s option to keep the current directory but it doesnt work as well.  When I echo `pwd` inside my.sh it shows the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to get it done. It was setting in the sudoer file to get the directories (the folder in with those files were) into safe path list.

All I had to do was,

```
run visudo
```

and append the two dolders (where the files are) into

```
Defaults secure_path  list
```

That will add those directories into the PATH when a user get elevated rights.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/128413/setting-the-path-so-it-applies-to-all-users-including-root-sudo

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo /abc/def/my.sh /absolute/path/to/myfile.env`

If myfile.sh is supposed to be in the same dir as my.sh, then my.sh can do this:

```
ENVFILE=$(dirname "$0")/"$1"
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, but I cant do that... i am not allowed to change the my.sh and it uses the file name (ie. $1 or "myfile.env") for some other work. If I pass the full path it breaks. Thanks for your suggestion though. Thats why I tries -s option to keep the current directory but it doesnt work as well. When I echo pwd inside my.sh it shows the correct path

Comment: Thanks for your input on myenv file... thats was just a sample. I am not doing what it does. Sorry If I mislead you..I'll update the question